# Making a Modified Fat Tire Clone

Tags: grain, taste, clone-recipe

This may be too specific but I will ask anyway.  I love Fat Tire but would like to modify a little.  The holy grail of beer would be a Fat Tire but more biscuit, more toasty caramel taste and fuller mouth feel. Any recommendations would be appreciated.  Even if it isn't a recipe, perhaps grains that present these specific tastes would help.

Comment: Googling for Fat Tire results with at least two things, belgian ale and american ale. Please be more specific about which one you want to clone.

Comment: Fat Tire is often miscategorized as a Belgian ale.  It is in fact an American amber.

Comment: @DennyConn Weird - f labels were identical I would assume error. But results I found was with photos of different labels... confusing coincidence? And why didn't you `@` me in your comment?

Comment: I want to say I read somewhere (just did a quick google search, but didn't find anything) that Fat Tire uses a blend of American ale yeast and Belgian ale yeast. Might be why there is confusion between the type and labels?

Comment: Concur with the comments that you should post a recipe if you really want a specific answer. Having recently done it myself, I'd say heed this warning - http://www.northernbrewer.com/connect/2010/07/ingredient-showcase-biscuit-malt/ - and maybe don't go too overboard with biscuit malt. Find a clone, bump the biscuit up and add or increase use of a crystal/caramel malt like Carapils. Increasing the portion of Munich malt by a lot might work too, but probably at the expense of a darker beer.

Comment: If you've ever tasted Fat Tire, you know there is nothing even vaguely "Belgian" about it in terms of flavors.  It was inspired by a bike ride in Belgium and that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

Zymurgy magazine has recipes for the the Amber and the Belgian.
Jul/Aug 2006 New Belgium Fat Tire Clone
Jul/Aug 2003 Fat Tire Amber Ale Clone
You have to be a member to access the recipes.

Here is a lot of clone recipes:
[Beersmith Recipes](http://beersmithrecipes.com/searchrecipe?term=fat%20tire&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)

Look at the recipes and determine what you think is a good median. Brew that. Taste and decide where that lands to what you wanted. You may want to increase the mash temp a degree or two (celcius). This will give you more body and will increase the residual sugars/sweetness.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, [this](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/showthread.php?t=211830) recipe [came from the original authors](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/showpost.php?p=2477610&postcount=2) of the beer you are cloning:

> Fat Tire Clone (December):
>
> 5 gal, OG = 1.050, FG = 1.013
>
> IBU = 19, SRM = 14, ABV = 4.7%
>
> - 8# 10 oz. 2-row Pale Malt
> - 1# Munich Malt
> - 8 oz. Crystal Malt (80L) 6
> - oz. Victory Malt
> - 0.4 oz. Target (60 min.)
> - 0.5 oz. Willamette (10 min.)
> - 0.5 oz. Goldings (0 min.) Wyeast 1272 or Wyeast 1792 or WLP051 Yeast

To modify, substitute some of base or munich with biscuit or melanoidin malts.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm sure you can find a good base recipe from the other answers, here's some suggestions for your modifications.*

**More Malt** consider a small Melonoiden Malt addition for Maillard notes (biscuit, bread crust, carmel)

**More Body** Body is mainly controlled by mash temperatures. Specifically the higher end of alpha-amylase temps for fuller body beers.